# Nested jQuery UI sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, nested, jquery-ui-sortable

I have some nested sortables, but when I try and move them around it has issues.

Sometimes it jumps around, and sometimes it tries to drop it above the parent instead of inside the box.

Anyway to make it consistent and work correctly?

Also when I set the tolerance mode to `pointer` it becomes impossible to drop it inside a child sortable.

http://jsfiddle.net/tFY59/4/

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
</div>

$('.wrapper, .box').sortable({
    connectWith: '.wrapper, .box',
    //tolerance: 'pointer',
    placeholder: 'placeholder ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all',
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    cursorAt: {
        left: -10
    },
    start: function() {
        $('.placeholder').append('<span>Move here...</span>');
    }.bind(this)
});
```

Comment: Not sure if this helps. But this is a great plugin for nestable behaviour https://github.com/dbushell/Nestable

Comment: @antony seems like that only works for lists.